# How to connect my php page to remote mongodb server?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, remote-connection

I need your help. I'm making a project for my thesis and I'm trying to fix this problem for a week without any results. I know that there are a lot of similar topics but I can swear that I didn't find nothing cocern my problem.

I have a web domain on "register.it" where my website has supposed to be. My website need to communicate and handle data from mongo database. So, I have also a remote server (with Ubuntu 16.04) where I install everything correctly (I followed an online guide and tested everything). In fact, locally (I mean, with the mongo shell), there aren't any problem. If I use "systemctl status mongod" it is active. These are other features of the environment:

- php 7.0.30
- mongodb 3.4.16
- mongodb driver 1.5.1
- mongodb database driver 1.6.16

Of course, I also added the extension in the "php.ini" file and allowed the connection from anywhere to the port 27017.

My simple page php have this code:

$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://user_of_db_admin:passwd_of_db_admin@151.236.61.166:27017/admin');
   echo "Connection to database successfull."

But it doesn't print anything. If I write only the echo, obviously, it will show the text. And if I write this code instead of the echo:

$dbs = $mongo->listDBs();
print_r($dbs);

the page will show this text "listDbs(); print_r($dbs);".
In others questions the users complaining because the page showed an error about the connection mongo function (or at least some error message), but I receive only text or a blank page.

I hope you could help me. If there are others information that you need, tell me and I will update my post.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code from the server? with the IP/url instead of from the page?

Comment: Mmmmh. Now I think I'm running the code not from the server but simply from my domain-web-space. But I thinked that the website could be on that domain and the server would listen and response to my pages. If it's not working like this, I don't know how to do it.
Maybe I have to use Plesk that is on the server? (In fact, the phpinfo() didn't work on my domain on register.it, but when I tried it on Plesk space it worked)

Comment: By any chance, did you forget to put the `<?php` before your code?

Comment: Also, you should check this to make sure your errors are showed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Yes, there's the <?php before my code.